# Trying to change text (heading) when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a message to the user after they select a radio button. I so far have set up what I think would work but after I select a radio button (in the case #1) nothing happens.

HTML:

```
    <div class="head">
        <h1>On A Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
        <h2 id=#head2></h2>
     </div>

     <div class="rating">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10"
        >10</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9"
        >9</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8"
        >8</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7"
        >7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6"
        >6</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5"
        >5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4"
        >4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3"
        >3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2"
        >2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1"
        >1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a> 
    </div>

    <script src="rating.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('rate1').checked){
document.querySelector("#head2").innerHTML= "Terrible";
}
```

Comment: The code above will run just one time on page load. You need to setup an event listener.

Answer (score 3):

You should add change event listener.

```js
document.getElementById('rate1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector("#head2").innerHTML= "Terrible"; 
});
```

```html
<div class="head">
        <h1>On A Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
        <h2 id="head2"></h2>
     </div>

     <div class="rating">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10"
        >10</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9"
        >9</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8"
        >8</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7"
        >7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6"
        >6</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5"
        >5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4"
        >4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3"
        >3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2"
        >2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1"
        >1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a> 
    </div>

    <script src="rating.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your H2 attribute.

Instead of `<h2 id=#head2></h2>`, it should be `<h2 id="head2"></h2>`

Answer (score 0):

(NOTE: check your HTML code as `<h2 id=#head2></h2>` should be `<h2 id="head2"></h2>`)

```js
const header = document.querySelector('#head2');

const radioOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=rating]');

/*
 * AFAIK, on MSIE 9 the 'change' event is triggered when the checkbox is unchecked
 * therefore when you make your first selection the event will not be triggered
 * hence the use of the 'click' event, instead.
 */
radioOptions.forEach(opt => opt.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let selectedOption;
  for (let i = 0; i < radioOptions.length; i++) {
    if (radioOptions[i].checked) {
      selectedOption = radioOptions[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  switch (parseInt(selectedOption.value)) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      header.innerText = "Terrible";
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      header.innerText = "Bad";
      break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
      header.innerText = "Fine";
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
      header.innerText = "Good";
      break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
      header.innerText = "Great";
      break;
    default:
      header.innerText = "";
  }
}));
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <h1>On A Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
  <h2 id="head2"></h2>
</div>

<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" value="10" name="rating" id="rate10">
  <label for="rate10">10</label>
  <input type="radio" value="9" name="rating" id="rate9">
  <label for="rate9">9</label>
  <input type="radio" value="8" name="rating" id="rate8">
  <label for="rate8">8</label>
  <input type="radio" value="7" name="rating" id="rate7">
  <label for="rate7">7</label>
  <input type="radio" value="6" name="rating" id="rate6">
  <label for="rate6">6</label>
  <input type="radio" value="5" name="rating" id="rate5">
  <label for="rate5">5</label>
  <input type="radio" value="4" name="rating" id="rate4">
  <label for="rate4">4</label>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="rating" id="rate3">
  <label for="rate3">3</label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="rating" id="rate2">
  <label for="rate2">2</label>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="rating" id="rate1">
  <label for="rate1">1</label>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a>
</div>

<script src="rating.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I show you how to write clean code with short syntax

1- first fixed first problem in your html code

```
<h2 id='head2'>Nothing yet</h2>
```

2- then write this code in your javascript , with this code you can do everything you like after click on every radio button,
also you can set desired condition with index like this:

```
if (index === 0){
  // your code
}
```

```
let radioList = document.getElementsByName('rating');
let header = document.querySelector("#head2");
radioList.forEach((radio, index) => {
  radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
    header.innerHTML = "Terrible" + '\t' + index; 
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a event listener.
With JQuery it is actually very easy:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

I would also recommend using a select input, if i look at your question.

But you would have to import the jquery library, with pure html it is like this:

```js
function inputChanged() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="inputChanged()">
  <option value="Happy">Happy</option>
  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="Sad">Sad</option>
  <option value="Depressed">Depressed</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

EDIT: Added a snippit in my code for easy demonstration.